# In eager mode, how to convert a tensor to a ndarray

Tags: python, tensorflow

How can I convert a tensor to a numpy array in eager mode?
In eager mode, I do not need to create a session, so I cannot use `.eval()`.

And I tried `tf.constant()`, it gives the following error:

`TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable'> to Tensor. Contents: <tf.Variable 'filters_C:0' shape=(2, 2) dtype=float32_ref>. Consider casting elements to a supported type.`

Here is the supporting code:

```
filters_C = tf.get_variable('filters_C',
                        shape=[2, 2],
                        initializer=tf.ones_initializer,
                        regularizer=None,
                        trainable=True)
filters_C = tf.constant(filters_C)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpy call the `numpy` method:

```
filters_C.numpy()
```

It is a [property of the `EagerTensor` class](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L723), which is the subclass of `Tensor` that is used by default in eager execution, which explains why this property pops up then.